# Пример POST запроса в формате json

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, api, post

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Требуется отправить запрос следующего формата:

```json
{
    "Id": "3d282e9547974355902282321723d955",
    "Language": "RU",
    "CustomRef": "",
    "Deals": [
        {
            "ExCode": "M",
            "Agreement": "100226-002V_260210",
            "Reference": "10000821159",
            "TradeDate": "2013-08-07",
            "Participant": "RBRSM",
            "Type": "S",
            "InName": "P",
            "OnAccount": "P",
            "Issue": "AIZK05",
            "Isin": "",
            "RegNum": "4-05-00739-A",
            "Qty": "7100",
            "Price": "17100000",
            "Currency": "RUR",
            "SettleDate": "2013-08-07"
        }
    ]
}
```

Правильно понимаю, что мой запрос должен быть таким? См. ниже. Все ли правильно?

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://api-domain.com'
data = {'Id': '3d282e9547974355902282321723d955',
        'Language': 'RU',
        'CustomRef':'',
        'Deals': [{"ExCode" : "M",
                    "Agreement" : "100226-002V_260210",
                    "Reference":  "10000821159",
                    }]}  
                      
answer = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data))
print(answer)
response = answer.json()
print(response)
```

Comment: Сама отправка выглядит правильно. Можно еще `json=data` вместо `data=json.dumps(data)`. Вот данные как я понимаю должны быть полностью в data, а не разбиты на data и headers - в примере у вас цельный json, не понятно почему вы решили, что кусок из него нужно перенести в headers.

Comment: Внес исправления. Посмотрите, пожалуйста. Так?

Comment: Да, по идее так. Я бы просто попробовал отправить, и посмотрел работает или нет.

Comment: Ok. Спасибо большое!